# Given series $a_n$ converges absolutely, then how to prove series $\log(1+a_n^4)$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Given series $a_n$ converges absolutely, then how to prove series $\log(1+a_n^4)$ converges.

Which test should I use?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hint:$$\log(1+x)\sim x$$ for small $x$.

Comment: Soi have to prove if $a_n$ is convergent then $a_n^4$ is convergent

Comment: yes and it is trivial.

Comment: @Vim how is it trivial?

Comment: well, $\sum a_n$ converges *absolutely* implies $|a_n|\to 0$, which again implies $|a_n|^4<1^3|a_n|$ for $n$ large enough, then...

Comment: Did you mean that $\sum_n a_n$ converges absoulutely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have from the absolute convergence of the series $\Rightarrow$ $|a_n| \to 0 \Rightarrow |a_n| \leq 1, n > N\Rightarrow |a_n|^4 \leq |a_n|, n > N\Rightarrow \log(1+a_n^4) \leq a_n^4 \leq |a_n|$, and the comparison test can be used to conclude.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

**Hint 2:** $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\log(1+x)}x=1$.

The Comparison Test should work.

Comment: Alternatively: $0 \le \log(1+x) \le x$ for $x \ge 0$.

Comment: OP just says $a_n$ converges, not $\sum a_n$ I think.

Comment: @Vim i meant the summation one, wrote series

Comment: @SophieClad then you should use $\sum$

Comment: @Vim: the other language (series, absolute convergence) indicated a series, not a sequence.

Comment: @robjohn Altight. Though I think it will be less ambiguous with a $\sum$ notation

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?